# What are common causes of crashes or problems on different Android phones when running PhoneGap app?

Tags: android, cordova, crash

I have PhoneGap application made for Android. On my device and other users devices it runs just fine. But on some phones ( right now I know about LG Optimus One and HTC Magic ) it doesn't start and / or crashes while starting.

Anybody has some good hints why could this happen ? I tried to run my app on Android emulator in all possible versions of Android and it runs fine. So its more of the hardware/phone problem.

Comment: as a side note, I'm developing a phonegap app right now use HTC magic.  Phonegap does not run well on this phone.  It is very slow.  Just clicking a link to display a hidden div takes about 1 second.  Based on my experience, I don't think phonegap is viable for this phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does an empty PhoneGap app work for you on the crashing devices? If so, I'd recommend binary search adding to the empty app [or reducing your work] until the crash occurs [crash stops].

The only feature (in the same app and Android version) I've seen cause crashes is the Camera. Different devices have different default resolutions and large resolutions can cause memory overflows.